# mootools json filter with groups

Tags: json, sorting, group-by, mootools

I have a json string. It looks like:

```
  var data= [{"name":"Name1","value":"Value1","group":"Group1","order":"1"},
      {"name":"Name2","value":"Value2","group":"Group1","order":"2"},
      {"name":"Name3","value":"Value3","group":"Group1","order":"3"},
      {"name":"Name4","value":"Value4","group":"Group2","order":"4"},
      {"name":"Name5","value":"Value5","group":"Group2","order":"5"},
      {"name":"Name6","value":"Value6","group":"Group3","order":"6"},
      {"name":"Name7","value":"Value7","group":"Group4","order":"7"},
      {"name":"Name8","value":"Value8","group":"Group4","order":"8"},
      {"name":"Name9","value":"Value9","group":"Group4","order":"9"}]
```

Is it possible to convert this into html output using mootools javascript library with sorting by order:

```
 <h2>Group1</h2> 
 <div>Name1 ... Value1</div>
 <div>Name2 ... Value2</div>
 <div>Name3 ... Value3</div>
 <h2>Group2</h2> 
 <div>Name4 ... Value4</div>
 <div>Name5 ... Value5</div>
 <h2>Group3</h2> 
 <div>Name6 ... Value6</div>
 <h2>Group4</h2> 
 <div>Name7 ... Value7</div>
 <div>Name8 ... Value8</div>
 <div>Name9 ... Value9</div>
```

This is my sorting function:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
   return parseInt(a.order) > parseInt(b.order);
});
```

My render function is follow:

```
var html_data = '';
data.each(function(d){      
       html_data += tmpl.render("data", d);            
}); 

container.set('html', html_data);
```

But I don't know how to group it.

Thanks!

Comment: yes it is possible. its not difficult either. you should have a go, post some code so then ppl can help you. look at the mootools api for Array methods for walking your response (.each, .map, .every etc) and say, String.prototype.substitute for the templating and outputting the objects. also, use a radix when you parseInt or use mootools' toInt() instead. your sort is not good either as you need to group by `group` and order may be local but you can solve that separately by extracting all groups and making the headings, then injecting underneath them as you find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test group for previous value in each loop:

```
var html_data = '';
var group = '';
data.each( function( item, index ) {
    if ( group !== item.group ) {
        html_data += '<h2>'+item.group+'</h2>';
    }
    html_data += '<div>'+item.name+'...'+item.value+'</div>';
    group = item.group;
});

container.set( 'html', html_data );
```